# Is this is happening because of the asynchronous nature of Node.js or is there any alternate way to achiece this?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

This is what I am trying to do.

I have an empty array

```
    var send_data = [] ;
```

and I am using "sync-each" npm library of node.js before that I was doing the iterations using the map callback function but got stuck in the same situation.

Here's my code.

```
    var each = require('sync-each');

    client.execute(someQuery,[value],(err,data) => {
    var items = data.rows;
    each(items,(items,next) => {
       // here I am performing some if-else queries and some Cassandra database queries and then pushing the value to my array send_data.
    if(items.type == true) {
       send_data.push({ value: items.message,flag:true });
    }else{
    send_data.push({value:items.message,flag:false});
    }
  },(err,transformedItems)=>{
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
    });
 });
```

My programs runs fine without getting any error but when I consoles the final output I get unsoreted list of array values like

```
     [{value:1},{value:3},{value:2},{value:4}]
```

Is there's a way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function which makes more sense for your case:

```js
 var items = [1,2,3,4];
 var send_data = items.map((item)=>({value:item}));
 console.log(send_data);
```

Comment: your approach is correct but it's not going with my project as I wants to add multiple key-value pairs and the value will be the query output of my database.

Comment: var send_data = items.map( (item) =>({ value: item.message, flag: item.type }));

Comment: The main problem was the asynchronous nature of node.js. What it was doing that it first performs all the iterations then all the complex database queries thats why I was getting jumbled up values but then to slolve this I used the sort-by library of npm and used this library to get sorting on the basis of time.